# How to use AngleSharp parse double div

Tags: c#, html

I have some html code like

```
<div><div>222</div>111</div>
```

So i want to get 111, but i can get it  222 111 now.
How can i only take 111?

This demo use AngleSharp
if use 
child.QuerySelector("div");
result is 222 111
if use 
var font = child.QuerySelector("div div");
result is 111

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.ParseDocument(aFile);
foreach (var child in tableChildren)
{
   var a = child.QuerySelector("div");
   var b = child.QuerySelector("div div");
}
```

So i want to get 111, but i can get it  222 111 now.
How can i only get 111?